# Pip install keeps throwing odd "ImportError"

Tags: installation, python, pip

I've been trying to install a few packages using pip and `pyudev` keeps throwing an import error. I have no idea where why it's only happening in pyudev. It installs just fine on my other computer. Here is the command and output:

```
$ sudo pip install pyudev

Collecting pyudev
  Downloading pyudev-0.16.1.tar.gz (74kB)
    100% |################################| 77kB 882kB/s 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-1Pk9rC/pyudev/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
      File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2310, in load
    return self.resolve()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
    ImportError: No module named version
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

    creating pip-egg-info/pyudev.egg-info

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip-build-1Pk9rC/pyudev/setup.py", line 55, in <module>

    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

      File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run

      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2310, in load

    return self.resolve()

      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in resolve

    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)

    ImportError: No module named version

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1Pk9rC/pyudev
```

UPDATE: As I dig around more, I've noticed that on my other computer it doesn't try to install "version".

UPDATE2: Well, I don't know WHY it was happening, but it's something with the python-daemon package. Here is another user with the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972349/installing-latest-python-daemon-2-0-3-breaks-subsequent-pip-installs

Update3: Just realized I failed to mention that uninstalling python-daemon fixed the problem. It was an old dependency and I no longer needed it. The newest release causes this problem.

Comment: works for me `pip uninstall python-daemon -y; pip install python-daemon==2.0.2` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972349/installing-latest-python-daemon-2-0-3-breaks-subsequent-pip-installs/

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pip itself first.

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: I did that. Didn't help. I upgraded pip and upgraded setuptools when that didn't work.